# Local behavior around critical points in high dimensions?

Tags: analysis, non-convex-optimization

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is (at least) $C^2$. In the standard calculus classes one learns: If the gradient of $f$ at $x_0$, then  $f$ has a local extremum (minimum or maximum) at $x_0$. Hence the gradient test is a necessary but not sufficient condition (as, e.g., $x\mapsto x^3$ shows). Using the (semi)positive/negative definiteness of the Hessian, one can disambiguate and identify among the previously found extremum candidates some that are local minima or maxima.

But so far this doesn't give *complete* classification of the extrema, as it is possible one the [one-dimensional case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Higher-order_derivative_test) for a test involving $n$ derivatives, and it seems that this problem is rather difficult for higher dimensions, involving potentially Morse theory, as I found it mentioned online.

Can someone clarify whether a nice, complete description (i.e. a nice characterization) of which points are minima and maxima exists in all dimension or point me to a definitive reference (that ideally also outlines the state of the art)?

There are various online references, that provide partial answers:

- [What is the higher-order derivative test in multivariable calculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2869744/what-is-the-higher-order-derivative-test-in-multivariable-calculus) (but this seems to give a test involving all derivatives, but following the discussion there it seems this test is rather hard to check in practice and one has to rely on numerical computations; in the comments it is actually stated **"there is not an analogue test in multivariable calculus"**, and this comment is backed up in the comments by a user I trust, KCd, which seems to indicate that the problem I outlined is open. Morse theory is mentioned, but not particular information is given. I would be also interested in a statement along the lines of whether for every $n$ one can construct a function such that for any "feasible" test using higher order derivatives, any "natural" test using higher order derivatives that allows "easy checking" fails.)
- [http://www.u.arizona.edu/~mwalker/MathCamp2021/UnconstrainedOptimization.pdf](http://www.u.arizona.edu/%7Emwalker/MathCamp2021/UnconstrainedOptimization.pdf) (this gives actually necessary and sufficient conditions, but I'm not happy with them, because they are different conditions, so the don't characterize extrema completely)
- https://www.ripublication.com/adsa20/v15n2p11.pdf (it's from 2020, but I'm not 100% convinced this is really a legit or novel article; nonetheless it's interested to read)

**EDIT:** I have also asked this question on [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432601/local-behavior-around-critical-points-in-high-dimensions) now.